# Migrating dependencies to Android Jetpack

Tags: android, gradle, android-jetpack

So I have been migrating my dependencies from support libraries to jetpack mappings as told in [this link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/refactor).

I now encouter an error while building my app which leaves me clueless. I have no idea what causes this error cause it looks like generated resources.

The error is:

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  C:\Users\Ruben\Documents\Bowvie\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:8673: error: expected reference but got (raw string) #000000.
error: failed linking references.

Command: C:\Users\Ruben\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-alpha14-4748712-windows.jar\90bbfcfb9476bccff8420ad6f86bed60\aapt2-3.2.0-alpha14-4748712-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\Ruben\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-P\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        C:\Users\Ruben\Documents\Bowvie\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        C:\Users\Ruben\Documents\Bowvie\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @C:\Users\Ruben\Documents\Bowvie\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        C:\Users\Ruben\Documents\Bowvie\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        nl.fdyr.movies\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        C:\Users\Ruben\Documents\Bowvie\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-alpha14-4748712-windows Daemon #0
```

The error line (8673) is:

```
<style name="Widget.Support.CoordinatorLayout" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="statusBarBackground">#000000</item>
</style>
```

The new migrated dependencies are:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'androidx.slice:slice-core:1.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'androidx.slice:slice-builders:1.0.0-alpha1'
```

Comment: What is line 8673 of `C:\Users\Ruben\Documents\Bowvie\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml`? Perhaps there is some clue as to where the resource is coming from, such as based on its name.

Comment: OK, well, it's not one of yours, presumably. It looks like it is from `CoordinatorLayout` itself. Off the cuff, it feels like a bug somewhere in the alpha releases. Try creating a new AS 3.2 project and pasting in those dependencies, and see what happens. If you get the same basic error, package up the project and file an issue.

Comment: I'm not sure where this style is coming from, but from AAPT2's point of view the statusBarBackground is an item, which means its value can either be empty or be a reference to another resource.

Comment: Having the same issue with AS3.2-Canary 14. The error is exactly the same one on the Support CoordinatorLayout `statusBarBackground`. I guess then it comes from the `CoordinatorLayout` and not from one of our projects

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After a ton of experimentation and searching it seems like the issue can be solved by overriding the style and setting the value in question `#000000` to `@null`.

In your `res/values/styles.xml` you can add

`<style name="Widget.Support.CoordinatorLayout" parent="android:Widget">
   <item name="statusBarBackground">@null</item>
</style>`

Which should override the original value and fix the issue.

Comment: The hex code is for the color black. The correct value is `@android:color/black`.